# Increment element by one

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

Using VB.NET & LINQ; I am writing to an XML file that I need to update the "click count". I am trying to create a function that will increment the element appClick by 1 each time someone clicks the link.

```
<applications>
  <app id="1">
    <appName>Service Desk</appName>
    <appLink>https://websiteurlhere.com</appLink>
    <appFav>1</appFav>
    <appClick>0</appClick>
  </app>
</applications>
```

So I have the subroutine that calls the applications and it is working perfectly. But is lacks the ability to increment the appClick element.

```vb
Public Sub appCall(ByVal x As String) ' x = application name
    Dim appQuery = _
        From c In doc.<applications>.<app> _
        Where c.<appName>.Value = x _
        Select c.<appLink>

    For Each result In appQuery
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(result.Value)
    Next
End Sub
```

If the code can be improved, I am also open to suggestions on that.

Comment: it's working perfectly, so what's the problem? What is your question?

Comment: The code that calls the application is working, but I don't know how to increment the appClick element when the subroutine is run. All it does right now is launch the application without the needed incrementation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just `Select c.<appLink>`, do a `Select c.<appClick>, c.<appLink>`.

Then you can do:

```vb
For Each result In appQuery
    result.appClick.Value += 1
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(result.appLink.Value)
Next
```

And don't forget to save your document after that.

```vb
doc.Save("fileName")
```

Here is a sample I used for testing:

```vb
Public Sub appCall(ByVal x As String) ' x = application name
  Dim doc = <applications>
              <app id="1">
                <appName>Service Desk</appName>
                <appLink>https://websiteurlhere.com</appLink>
                <appFav>1</appFav>
                <appClick>0</appClick>
              </app>
            </applications>

  Dim appQuery = _
      From c In doc.<app> _
      Where c.<appName>.Value = x _
      Select c.<appClick>, c.<appLink>

  For Each result In appQuery
    result.appClick.Value += 1
    Debug.WriteLine(result.appLink.Value)
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Exactly what I was looking for. I will come back and vote it up as soon as I have the reputation points.